# x-axis and y-axis overflow

Tags: javascript, css

A) How can I set scroll to always appear on x and Y acies ?

I have unsuccessfuly tried:

```
#jstree {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

B) I have the bottom stip, I want it overrides the folders tree.

I want it to appear 10px below the tree div.

See photo:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting overflow to auto, that won't work

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: Tried that as well. same results.

Comment: adjust the height of B so that it's only 1 pixel below that way it looks like it's farther., but it really isn't and the scroll should show.